# json value not fetching from localhost to angularjs frontend

Tags: json, angularjs

This my javascript part i am not able to get any response from $http.get
can anyone suggest a solution

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/load")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="data in names">
    {{ data.name + ', ' + data.age }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you know that http://localhost:3000/load is returning a value?

Comment: Why you are using http://localhost ?? use your application path /webapp path from where you want to fetch data

Comment: @capnSparrow yes i am getting json value

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I am using nodejs to fetch data from mysql database,and its passed as json to  http://localhost:3000/load

Comment: @Vineet actually i am getting a console error   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJS documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

No localhost:3000, just use '/load'.

No '.success', use '.then'

Comment: @Dmithri I tried the above code its still not working

Comment: thanks everyone for the help i got it working this was a CORS issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var Response = $http.get( $window.location.pathname + your url); //put your url here
        Response.success( function ( data ) {

        $scope.Names = data;
        } );
         Response.error( function ( data ) {
            $scope.error = data;
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular code has to change like @Dmitri Algazin has suggested. Check below code and the JS Fiddle

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/load")
.then(function(response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeHawkz/bs47qbv2/)